# How do you insert into one table based on the ID (as foreign key) of another table?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, sql-update, ddl

I am trying to create some characters in a c# game. I have two tables, tbl_user which handles user info, and tbl_player that is their character. These tables are shown below:

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
    `userID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `user_password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `user_loginStatus` tinyint(1) default false NOT NULL,
    `user_loginAttempts` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `user_accountStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `user_isAdmin` tinyint(1) default false NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
);
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `playerID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `player_score` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `Character` VARCHAR(20) default null,
    `gameID` INTEGER default null,
    `tileID` INTEGER default null,
    `userID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`playerID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`gameID`) REFERENCES `tbl_game`(`gameID`) ON DELETE CASCADE  ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`tileID`) REFERENCES `tbl_tile`(`tileID`) ON DELETE CASCADE  ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `tbl_user`(`userID`) ON DELETE CASCADE  
);
```

I would like to insert the player details (i.e character, tileID, and userID) based off the username from the user table. When I do an inner join, this is the result I get from this ddl script:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_player INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_player.userID = tbl_user.userID;
```

[image]

Is there a way where I can select username from tbl_user and set the values in tbl_player based on ids that match and usernames that match that ID? I tried this, but I believe that it doesn't work in MySQL or the syntax is wrong:

```
UPDATE tbl_player SET gameID = 1, tileID =0, `Character` = "Wizard" FROM tbl_player INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_player.userID = tbl_user.userID WHERE username = "example",
```

Comment: What values do you want to set in tbl_player table? Hardcoded ones like this: gameID = 1, tileID =0, `Character` = "Wizard"  or?

Comment: Yes, those three

Comment: A user enters there username into a field when they are creating a character which is how I want to connect the two tables rather than doing it off their ID

Comment: Is this possible? @Filip

Comment: If you want those values to be hardcoded, then I think your query looks fine. Can you show us the exact error that you are receiving with that update query?

Comment: it says that From is not valid in this position

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL doesn't support the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax you're using, as far as I know. You'll want to use something like `UPDATE tbl_player p JOIN tbl_user u ON p.userID = u.userID SET p.gameID = 1, p.titleID = 0, p.\`Character\` = 'Wizard' WHERE u.username = 'example'`